# Flux Quantization in a Compact $U(1)$ Gauge Theory in 2+1D

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory

I was reading through the Gauge Theory section on Xiaogang Wen's textbook on Quantum Field Theory of Many Body Systems.

In this chapter, he talks about a compact $U(1)$ gauge theory in $2+1 D$, where the Lagrangian is given as
$$L = \frac{1}{2g^2}(e^2-b^2) \,, \ e_i = \partial_0 a_i - \partial_i a_0 \,, \ b_0 = \partial_1 a_2 - \partial_2 a_1 $$
He says around Eq. 6.3.6 that in order for the gauge field $a_i$ to be gauge equivalent under the periodic boundary conditions, $x_1 \rightarrow x_1 + L_1$, and $x_2 \rightarrow x_2 + L_2$, the total flux has to be quantized as $\int d^2 x \ b = \frac{2\pi N}{q}$. He later also says that in order to prove this, one needs to make use of the expansion,

$$a_i = X_i(t)/L_i + b_0 x_1 \delta_{i,2} + \sum_k i c_k(t) \epsilon_{ij} k_j e^{i k \cdot x} $$

I am not sure how you can prove the flux quantization with the above equation - for one, the charge isn't defined at all in the Lagrangian or in the above expansion, and it only comes in once we introduce the Wegner-Wilson loop amplitude of $O(C) = e^{i q \oint_C d x^\mu a_\mu} $.

Anyone know how to do this?